# Using iOS's database on Android

Tags: android, database, ios, sqlite

I am working on an Android application that will access the database that is already preloaded with data. At the same time, I also have an iOS's sqlite database that has the same data that I need.

So I was wondering, can I just use iOS's database and load that into my Android application? I found this [website](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/comment-page-6/#comments) that teaches you how to load your own database into Android but somehow iOS's database is not loading properly in my application. Can someone help me in this situation?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I have successfully loaded my iOS databases using that technique.  What error are you seeing?  It would help to see some of your code.